# VB.net drop last octat from ipaddress (after 3rd decimal)

Tags: vb.net, string, truncation

I have an ip address as follows 192.168.10.140 
i would like to drop everything from the string after the 3rd occurance of the decimal
but i am not  sure how to go about it

using VB.net 2010

thanks in advance

Comment: i tried a truncate after looping to the third decimal but since this post i found lastindexof that i am trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LastIndexOf` to find the last index of `.` then use `Substring` to get the part you need.

Comment: thanks found this before i saw yours it it works with one line clientSocket.Connect(Mid(_IP, 1, _IP.LastIndexOf(".")) & Mid(portname, 4, portname.Length - 3), 8888) .  where _IP is the ipaddress of local machine and the last part of portname has the last part of ip i want to connect to